# Making a .dmg available for download from a website

Tags: url, browser, download, dmg

Good day lovely computer peoples!

I've uploaded a .dmg file to my server, but when I test to see if it is downloadable by pointing the web browser to it's place in the directory (i.e. using it's URL) I get a 404.

Any possible ideas of why this could be happening?

Thanks

---

EDIT 1

I realize that the 404 means that it can't find the item, but I'm staring at both addresses (the one in the browser and the one in the FTP client that I use) and they seem identical. I have some underscores in the name of the .dmg. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you add a mime type for the file extension. Most servers now days do not allow access to files that don't have explicit file extension declarations in their list of mime types.

You didn't say what server you're using so I can't give you specific instructions on how to do it but in most servers it's fairly easy. Just google your webserver name and "add mime type" with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The myfile.dmg is not found. Double check the file location and the URL you are pointing to.